# How does list mapping in dart actually work?

Tags: list, dictionary, dart

I am coming from a javascript background, and in javascript if i had an array with elements `[1,2,3]` I can map through this array and perform a function on each iteration as so:

```
[1,2,3].map((i) => {
    console.log(i);
    return;
})
```

and i get

```
1
2
3
```

Trying same in dart

```
void main() {
  [1, 2, 3].map((i) {
    print(i);
    return;
  });
}
```

No output is printed, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is different from Dart.

According to the [documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Iterable/map.html), the `map` method on an `Iterable` is meant to

> return a new **lazy** `Iterable` with elements that are created by calling `f` on each element of this Iterable in iteration order.

In other words, the function in the `map` method isn't called until it is needed because it is **lazi**ly invoked. It will not return anything until something asks for what it is supposed to return. *As long as the returned Iterable is not iterated over, the supplied function `f` will not be invoked.*

Try in [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev)

```dart
void main() {
  var arr = [1, 2, 3];
  var arr2 = arr.map((item)=> {
     item * 2
  });
  print ('$arr2');
}
```

In the example above, the function in the `map` method of `arr` is called/invoked because it is requested for by `$arr2` in the print function. Because of this, it runs the code inside it and the parameter in the `print` method gets printed out

Try

```dart
  print([1, 2, 3].map((i) {
    print(i);
    return;
  }));
```

You'll see that you get your desired result, because the function in the `map` method was invoked by the `print` method.

Since the method is **lazy**, it will not be invoked until it is requested. Adding a `map` method to an array doesn't invoke it. You've got to require what it returns for the function in the `map` method to be invoked.